# I want to get rid of unneccessary repetiton of cycles

Tags: c#, performance, array

I have a code that should read diameters of barrels from a txt file. If a barrel is smaller than the last one, smaller gets put inside bigger one. One package like that is lied on a stack. at the end, code should give out how many stacks we get and how many barrels were in a file. also sum of diameters.

If one number is repeated 3 times, we get 3 stack, if we have 5 repeating nmbers, then 5.
What can I do that I wouldn´t have to write simillar blocks n times.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace TaaviSimsonTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\\temp\\andmed2"))
            {
                int sum = 0;
                string line = string.Empty;
                List<int> numbersList = new List<int>();
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)   
                {
                    int i = int.Parse(line);    
                    sum += i;
                    numbersList.Add(int.Parse(line));
                }
                int[] numbersListArray = numbersList.ToArray();
                int numberOfStacks = numbersListArray.Length;
                //Max number of stacks equals to inital array length

                Array.Sort(numbersListArray);       //Array is ascending orded
                Array.Reverse(numbersListArray);    //Array in descending order
                
                //Puts smaller barrels inside bigger. Decreases number of stacks.
                List<int> repeatedBrarrelSizes = new List<int>();
                for (int j = 0; j < (numbersListArray.Length - 1); j++)
                {
                    if (numbersListArray[j] > numbersListArray[j + 1])
                    {
                        numberOfStacks--;
                    } 
                    else if (numbersListArray[j] == numbersListArray[j + 1])
                    {
                        repeatedBrarrelSizes.Add(numbersListArray[j + 1]);
                    }
                }
                int[] repeatedBarrelSizesArray = repeatedBrarrelSizes.ToArray();

                //Repeats the cycle with repeating numbers
                List<int> repeatedBarrelSizes2 = new List<int>();
                for (int k = 0; k < (repeatedBarrelSizesArray.Length-1); k++)
                {
                    if (repeatedBarrelSizesArray[k] > repeatedBarrelSizesArray[k+1])
                    {
                        numberOfStacks--;
                    }
                    else if (repeatedBarrelSizesArray[k] == repeatedBarrelSizesArray[k + 1])
                    {
                        repeatedBarrelSizes2.Add(repeatedBarrelSizesArray[k + 1]);
                    }
                }
                int[] repeatedBarrelSizes2Array = repeatedBarrelSizes2.ToArray();

                //Repeats the cycle again, until no barrels left
                List<int> repeatedBarrelSizes3 = new List<int>();
                for (int k = 0; k < (repeatedBarrelSizes2Array.Length - 1); k++)
                {
                    if (repeatedBarrelSizes2Array[k] > repeatedBarrelSizes2Array[k + 1])
                    {
                        numberOfStacks--;
                    }
                    else if (repeatedBarrelSizes2Array[k] == repeatedBarrelSizes2Array[k + 1])
                    {
                        repeatedBarrelSizes3.Add(repeatedBarrelSizes2Array[k + 1]);
                    }
                }
                int[] repeatedBarrelSizes3Array = repeatedBarrelSizes3.ToArray();

                foreach (int value in repeatedBarrelSizes3Array)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value + " ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + sum);
                Console.WriteLine("Number of barrels: " + numbersListArray.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Stacks: " + numberOfStacks);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself.

If you have repeating parts of code, something went wrong then. Also you may use `Linq`.

Consider this example.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\andmed2");
    List<int> numbersList = lines.Select(line => int.Parse(line)).OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
    int sum = numbersList.Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x + y);
    int numberOfStacks = numbersList.Count;

    List<int> repeatedBarrelSizes = numbersList;
    int count;
    do
    {
        count = 0;
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeatedBarrelSizes.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (repeatedBarrelSizes[i] > repeatedBarrelSizes[i + 1])
                count++;
            else if (repeatedBarrelSizes[i] == repeatedBarrelSizes[i + 1])
                result.Add(repeatedBarrelSizes[i + 1]);
        }
        repeatedBarrelSizes = result;
        numberOfStacks -= count;
    } while (count > 0);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", repeatedBarrelSizes));

    Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + sum);
    Console.WriteLine("Number of barrels: " + numbersList.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("Stacks: " + numberOfStacks);
}
```

*I'm sorry but I can't test it because I have no source file with numbers to compare the results.*

**Total:** two loops.