# Solving code without extra cycle outside for loop

Tags: c#, array

This code reads barrel diameter and height from file, then, based on dimension make decisions and finally these decisions are printed out to a file. My pronbelm is how to avoid using the code wrtine on lines 70-101? Probably has to do with line 35, but I haven´t figured my way around it. Would be nice if there is a way (chance) to make this code shorter.

P.S d - diameter, h - height

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
     
    namespace TaaviSimsonTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Reads values from an input file
                var numbersList = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\temp\\vaaditest07.txt")
                    .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                    .Select(barrels => new
                    {
                        diameter = int.Parse(barrels[0]),
                        height = int.Parse(barrels[1])
                    })
                    .ToArray();
     
                //Puts diameter and height values to arrays
                int[] d = numbersList.Select(x => x.diameter).ToArray();
                int[] h = numbersList.Select(x => x.height).ToArray();
     
                //Displays numbersList with line number, diameter and height
                for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: diameter: {1}, height: {2}", 
                        i, d[i], h[i]);
                }
     
                //comparing barrel sizes and making a decision
                List<string> output = new List<string>();
                for (int j = 0; j < (d.Length - 1); j++)
                {
                    int a = j + 1;
                    int b = j + 2;
                    if (d[j] > d[j + 1] && h[j] > h[j+1])
                    {
                        string command = a + "<-" + b;  //1 <- 2, if j = 0
                        output.Add(command);            //puts command in array
                    }
                    else if (d[j] < d[j + 1] && h[j] < h[j+1])
                    {
                        string command = a + "->" + b;
                        output.Add(command);
                    }
                    else if (d[j+1] < h[j] &&       
                        ((d[j+1] * d[j+1] + h[j+1] * h[j+1]) <
                        d[j] * d[j]))
                    {
                        string command = a + "<-" + b;  // 2 <- 3
                        output.Add(command);
                    }
                    else if(d[j] < h[j+1] &&    
                        ((d[j] * d[j] + h[j] * h[j]) <
                        d[j+1] * d[j+1]))
                    {
                        string command = a + "->" + b;
                        output.Add(command);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string command = a + "--" + b;
                        output.Add(command);
                    }
                }
     
                //how to avoid this cycle?
                int c = 1;
                int e = d.Length;
                if (d[0] > d[d.Length - 1] && h[0] > h[d.Length - 1])    
                {
                    string command = c + "<-" + e;
                    output.Add(command);
                }
                else if (d[0] < d[d.Length - 1] && h[0] < h[d.Length-1])  
                {
                    string command = c + "->" + e;
                    output.Add(command);
                }
                else if (d[d.Length-1] < h[0] && 
                    ((d[d.Length-1] * d[d.Length-1] + h[d.Length-1] * h[d.Length-1]) < 
                    d[0] * d[0]))
                {
                    string command = c + "<-" + e;
                    output.Add(command);
                }
                else if (d[0] < h[d.Length-1] &&    
                    ((d[0] * d[0] + h[0] * h[0]) <  
                    d[d.Length-1]*d[d.Length-1]))
                {
                    string command = c + "->" + e;
                    output.Add(command);
                }
                else
                {
                    string command = c + "--" + e;
                    output.Add(command);
                }
     
                //Writes values of array to a new file
                String[] outputlist = output.ToArray();
                File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Temp\barrelsOutput.txt", outputlist);
                //Displaying output in console
                Console.WriteLine("");
                foreach (var item in outputlist)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give a feedback to [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/250335/226545) or accept it?

Answer (score 11):

**Some Notes :**

- you should make your code more readable more often. This would give your code more sense even for yourself, specially if you reviewed it in the future.
- you need to consider naming convention like using Pascal Casing for Properties, naming your variables with meaningful names.
- Don't split the string without validating first.
- Don't `Parse` values directly such as `int.Parse` unless you're sure it will be a valid value, instead use `int.TryParse` to avoid exceptions.
- Don't create an array from anonymous type (or any other type) array unless if is needed (in your case it's not needed) instead, use the array that you've created.
- Always if you see some redundancy in your code (repetitive code) move it to a method, this way you can reuse the method and your adjustments would be in one place.
- `File.WriteAllLines` accepts `IEnumerable` this means, you can pass the `List<string>` directly, so no need to convert it to array.
- `string.Join` can concatenate a `List` or `Array` into one `string` so use that to your advantage.
- Always validate your values as much as possible, this would give more stability to your code, and ensure your results.

Your question regarding this part of code :

```
if (d[0] > d[d.Length - 1] && h[0] > h[d.Length - 1])    
{
    string command = c + "<-" + e;
    output.Add(command);
}
else if (d[0] < d[d.Length - 1] && h[0] < h[d.Length-1])  
{
    string command = c + "->" + e;
    output.Add(command);
}
else if (d[d.Length-1] < h[0] && 
    ((d[d.Length-1] * d[d.Length-1] + h[d.Length-1] * h[d.Length-1]) < 
    d[0] * d[0]))
{
    string command = c + "<-" + e;
    output.Add(command);
}
else if (d[0] < h[d.Length-1] &&    
    ((d[0] * d[0] + h[0] * h[0]) <  
    d[d.Length-1]*d[d.Length-1]))
{
    string command = c + "->" + e;
    output.Add(command);
}
else
{
    string command = c + "--" + e;
    output.Add(command);
}
```

This part needs to be moved into a method and make it more generalized to be reused, like this :

```
private static string GetCommand(int currentDiameter , int nextDiameter , int currentHeight , int nextHeight)
{
    var currentDiameterMultiplied = currentDiameter * currentDiameter;
    var nextDiameterMultiplied = nextDiameter * nextDiameter;
    var currentHeightMultiplied = currentHeight * currentHeight;
    var nextHeightMultiplied = nextHeight * nextHeight;

    if(currentDiameter > nextDiameter && currentHeight > nextHeight)
    {
        return "<-";
    }

    if(currentDiameter < nextDiameter && currentHeight < nextHeight)
    {
        return "->";
    }

    if(nextDiameter < currentHeight && ( ( nextDiameterMultiplied + nextHeightMultiplied ) < currentDiameterMultiplied ))
    {
        return "<-";
    }

    if(currentDiameter < nextHeight && ( ( currentDiameterMultiplied + currentHeightMultiplied ) < nextDiameterMultiplied ))
    {
        return "->";
    }

    return "--";
}
```

now you can reuse it in your code, here is the modified version of your code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Reads values from an input file
    var path = "C:\\temp\\vaaditest07.txt";
    
    if(!File.Exists(path)) { throw new FileNotFoundException(nameof(path)); }
        
    var data = File.ReadAllLines(path); 
    
    if(data == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data)); }
    
    var numbersList = data
                        .Select(line => 
                            line.Split(' ')
                                .Select(barrels => new
                                {                       
                                    Diameter = int.TryParse(barrels[0], out var diameter) ? diameter : 0,
                                    Height = int.TryParse(barrels[1], out var height) ? height : 0
                                }).ToArray();

    //comparing barrel sizes and making a decision
    var output = new List<string>();

    var length = numbersList.Length;
    
    var command = string.Empty;
    
    for(int index = 0, nextIndex = 1; index < length; index++, nextIndex++)
    {  
        var current = numbersList[index];
        
        var next = numbersList[nextIndex];

        // Displays numbersList with line number, diameter and height
        Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: diameter: {1}, height: {2}" , index , current.Diameter , current.Height);

        if(index != length - 1)
        {   
            var commandSymbol = GetCommand(current.Diameter , next.Diameter , current.Height , next.Height);
            command = $"{nextIndex}{commandSymbol}{nextIndex + 1}";   
        }
        else 
        {
            var commandSymbol = GetCommand(numbersList[0].Diameter , current.Diameter , numbersList[0].Height , current.Height);
            command = $"{0}{commandSymbol}{length}";                
        }
        
        output.Add(command);
    }
    
    // Writes values of array to a new file
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Temp\barrelsOutput.txt" , output);

    //Displaying output in console
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. At first I wrote diameter and height out, but then I changed it to d and h, to try and make it shorter. Though I understand it makes reading code harder, which is not good. I will try out your version at the next free moment and give you feedback.

Comment: I tried your code, but for some reason it gives me four errors.
Line 19. Argument 1: Cannot convert from string[] to string
Line 21. string[] does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no accessible extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type string[] could be found
Line 46: The name "GetCommand" does not exist in the current context
Line 51: The name "GetCommand" does not exist in the current context

Comment: I forgot to copy method part, but it still gives named errors on lines 19 and 21

Comment: @TaaviSimson sorry, I didn't test the code, I just revised it outside the compiler. I've fixed the issue. `File.ReadAllLines` returns `string[]` so I should iterate over its elements and split them. Which I missed, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice starting with writing code that is actually readable. Also from your question I don't really know what your goal is.

Do you want short code that get the job done? Then I'd say you are already there. If you want readable and maintainable code, then maybe try an OO approach where you encapsulate bits of code into objects which with their name and methods you document what you are actually doing.

Because I'm waaaay too lazy to interpret what you are trying to do at lines 70-101. I wanna read the names and titles and know it.

So, that is my two cents

Comment: OP has fulfill the minimum requirement to have a valid question, if you have any confusion regarding OP question, feel free to use the comment section before posting an answer.